# Draw only part of a path

Tags: android, canvas, path, draw, clip

I have a fullscreen custom view in my activity where I have to draw paths that are formed by a line each one. Since my view supports scaling, depending on how zoomed in the view is, the paths get to big and therefore the view becomes slow, even crashing sometimes. What I want to know is if there's some built-in function where I can draw only the part of the path that is actually inside the canvas.

I've tried using Path.op with a rect the size of the screen, but didn't get any results; it either returns an empty path or a path that contours the screen. Same thing with Canvas.clipPath(). Passing a rect on through invalidate() also doesn't work for me since the said path IS insterecting the drawing area.

It's also worth metioning that I'm using paths because I need to use a PathDashPath effect. So, if there's a way os doing that with drawLine, it'd also help.

Comment: Everything is already clipped to the view by default. Your slow down is the result of something else. Hard to tell without the code but a very zoomed in path with dash effects can be slow on some devices. Not much you can do about it apart from finding another way of rendering the path. Without code we can only guess.

Comment: Agree with Blindman.  The issue is likely in your logic es where to draw the line check id the points are outside of your canvas, if so dont draw them.(probably excessive loops), not the underlying mechanisms that do the drawling.  A couple things to try, 1. Use the RequestAnimationFrame function to do your drawling not a setInterval timer. 2. In your loop that determin